# Validating model realted to another in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

Is it possible to make Laravel's validation rule like this pseudo-code?

```
field1 in modelA must be lower than sum of field2, field3 and field4 from modelB
```

I have no idea, how to do it...

Comment: I'm guessing the value is of `field1` is the one being passed to the validator. What's unclear is if you want that value to be lower than the sum for any entry in ModelB's table, or just lower than an entry of type ModelB with a specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to compare to a ModelB with a specific ID or the lowest sum of any ModelB entry, so here are custom validation rules for both cases.

#### 1. Compare agains a ModelB with a specific ID:

```
lower:model_name,id,field_name1,field_name2,field_name3,...,field_nameN
```

You can add as many fields for summing as you want (not just 3, like in your example). The validator code would look like this:

```
Validator::make(
    array('field1' => 5),
    array('field1' => 'lower:ModelB,1,field2,field3,field4')
);
```

The validation rule would look like this:

```
Validator::extend('lower', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Get model name from first parameter
    $modelName = array_shift($parameters);
    // Get id from second parameter
    $id = array_shift($parameters);

    // Create a model instance
    $model = App::make($modelName)->find($id);

    // Calculate sum
    $sum = array_sum(array_map(function ($field) use ($model) {
        return $model->{$field};
    }, $parameters));

    // Return validation result
    return $value < $sum;
});
```

#### 2. Compare agains the lowest sum of any ModelB entry:

```
lower:model_name,field_name1,field_name2,field_name3,...,field_nameN
```

Same as previous rule but without the ID as the second parameter. The validator code would look like this:

```
Validator::make(
    array('field1' => 5),
    array('field1' => 'lower:ModelB,field2,field3,field4')
);
```

The validation rule would look like this:

```
Validator::extend('lower', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Get model name from first parameter
    $modelName = array_shift($parameters);

    // Calculate sum
    $sum = App::make($modelName)->select(DB::raw('(' . implode('+', $parameters) . ') as sum'))->get()->min('sum');

    // Return validation result
    return $value < $sum;
});
```

This could also be done using table names and `DB` instead of models.